# Excel js API - Making Cell Appear When Calling Range.Select()

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I'm using Office.js in a javascript Office Add-in. 
In Desktop Excel 365 (version 2003 build 12624.20382), when a cell is selected through js, it receives the focus, but it does not come into view for the user, the worksheet doesn't scroll to the selected cell.

```
Excel.run(async function (ctx) {
    var Sheet;
    var Tbl;
    var BodyRange;

    Sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem('sheetName');
    Tbl = Sheet.tables.getItem('tableName');
    BodyRange = Tbl.getDataBodyRange();
    BodyRange.getCell(0,0).select();

    await ctx.sync(); 
});
```

This is issue has been raised two years ago with Office 2016, but it didn't come to a conclusion.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your gist in Excel Desktop Version 2004( build 12730.20150), 
the `range.select()` does scroll to the selected cell.

I also tried Excel Mac (version 16.36) and Excel Online, all 3 platforms work as expected.

This is the screen short:

[image]

This is the gist i am using https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/430c2b51cb7fecd2d70676f2b4c6c136

I think we could do 2 things:

- can you please try my gist in your side and see if you can repro this issue?
- could you send your gist to me, I can verify in my side.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried on version 2005 build 12813.20000, I can't repro on my side. I tried your code targeting a table out of current view, the selected range can come into the view after execution.

Seems your version just 2 months behind mine, is that possible for you to update the excel ?

Comment: Thanks, but it says the version is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

Basically, my procedure select and fill an Excel table and then select the first cell; as first instructions, I set these properties to speed up and then fill the table and select the cell:

```
        ctx.application.suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync();
        ctx.application.suspendScreenUpdatingUntilNextSync();
        ctx.runtime.enableEvents = false;
```

Since screen updating is set to false until next sync, the cell is selected, but the view doesn't change.

I solved it syncing the context after filling the table and then I select the cell.

Thanks everyone